# WaitNamedPipe does not wait

Tags: c++, windows, named-pipes

I have a pipe (server) on one process waiting for clients  with `ConnectNamedPipe`.
In the client process I'm waiting for the server to start listening with `WaitNamedPipe`, I gave it a timeout of 5000 ms.
I tried testing the client and even though the server wasn't running, `WaitNamedPipe` didn't wait at all.

I don't know if any code would be helpful here because I just try to use those methods. But if you want to see something, just tell me what is relevant. :)

oh, and the weird part is that it gave me error code 2: "file not found'.
Isn't it supposed to wait until the pipe is opened (the pipe is the "file", isn't it?)

What can cause `WaitNamedPipe` not wait?

Comment: It sounds like the pipe doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not wait for a pipe to come into existence, it waits for an existing pipe to become available (i.e. an outstanding `ConnectNamedPipe`):

> If no instances of the specified named pipe exist, the WaitNamedPipe
>   function returns immediately, regardless of the time-out value.

Comment: my pipe in the server is calling ConnectNamedPipe. So it means that I call "WaitNamedPipe" before the pipe in the server is created?

Comment: It will fail if its called before the pipe exists